# App goes minimize when multiple click events on screen or button while navigate to another screen

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, minimize, start-activity

When i click login button i navigate to home screen from login screen while clicking multiple times on screen or login button, app goes to minimize. But when i reopen or resume app it navigated to home screen.

But problem is that why it goes to minimize.

I attached code for navigate to home screen.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Please help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post code for both Login and Home Activity.

Answer (score 0):

This is weird! But maybe the login button is at the bottom of the screen and accidentally the user is clicking the home button. In the other hand, if it is not the case you can try the following approach. If for any reason the application is going to background (app goes to minimize) and the reason is in the logic of the button you can try to disable the button when the user clicks on the login button, if the login logic fails, enable the login button. If the login is success keep it disable, it guaranteed that the code will execute once. And the user can not click it multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but my login button is at bottom there is much more between button and bottom

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
// please remove below line 
// This line remove your Activity so when you press back pressed cant recover 
   last activity 
//  finish();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I finish it because i don't want to recover that login screen.

Comment: can you please elaborate the question so i can give answer